# What's the best way to transfer a large dataset over an ASMX web service?

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx, large-data-volumes

I've inherited a C# .NET application which talks to a web service, and the web service talks to an Oracle database.  I need to add an export function to the UI, to produce an Excel spreadsheet of some of the data.

I have created a web service function to run a database query, load the data into a DataTable and then return it, which works fine for a small number of rows.  However there is enough data in the full run that the client application locks up for a few minutes and then returns a timeout error.  Obviously this isn't the best way to retrieve such a large dataset.

Before I go ahead and come up with some dodgy way of splitting the call, I'm wondering if there is already something in place that can handle this.  At the moment I'm thinking of a startExport function then repeatedly calling a next50Rows function until there is no data left, but because web services are stateless this means I'm going to have to keep some sort of ID number around and deal with the associated permissions.  It would mean that I don't have to load the entire data set into the web server's memory though, which is one good thing.

So if anyone knows a better way to retrieve a large amount of data (in a table format) over aN ASMX web service, please let me know!

Comment: How much data? Are you sure it is the amount of data, not possible the query or something else that's causing this?

Comment: It could be the query, it's only a few thousand rows of data.  It only comes back at about 100k/sec on a 100Mbps network.  But I imagine the problem is still the same - the data takes a long time to arrive, the client app doesn't get any feedback to know what's going on, so it eventually times out.

Answer (score 6):

We had this exact business scenario a few years ago, and I'll tell you what we did.

1. Try to limit the amount of data transferred
2. If you're transferring n tables, split them into n datatables and transfer one datatable at a time.
3. Compress your dataset/datatable before transferring.  This makes a huge (huge huge) impact.  On the other side, decompress the byte stream back into a dataset/datatable.  Don't use .NET's built in compression either - use SharpZipLib.  It gives much better results.
4. Also, you can perform the transfer asynchronously to keep the client from locking up.

Our customers have been using the above solution, without issue, for years.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Normally this would work fine, but in my particular case it's just one big table that needs to be transferred  so it can't be split up into smaller tables.  Since it only runs at 100k/sec over a 100Mbps network I don't think compression would help, and even asynchronously it still takes long enough for the call to time out :-(

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you just want to call the web service asynchronously, so your application doesn't block on UI while it's all going on. Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233842.aspx and see if it helps.

Comment: -1: that's about ASMX web services, which are a legacy technology. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7bkzywba.aspx and many other pages.

Comment: @Malvineous are you using asmx or WCF? I can update the answer with a WCF link...

Comment: I am using ASMX (I think, the web service URL ends in .asmx) because that's what the app came with.  Putting the call in another thread probably won't help that much, because I will still get the timeout error on the client.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend offloading the task to SSRS, which handles long-running queries without a problem. You can build a report with your report builder, then use your .NET app to invoke the SSRS web services run your report and export the results back in Excel format (as a byte array). See [this page](http://blog.ponytailbob.com/2007/11/rendering-ssrs-2005-reports-with-web.html) for sample code using the .asmx service, and [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20201125113428/http://geekswithblogs.net/stun/archive/2010/02/26/executing-reporting-services-web-service-from-asp-net-mvc-using-wcf-add-service-reference.aspx) for invoking SSRS with WCF.

You should also call your webservice in a separate thread to avoid tying up your UI.

Answer (score 2):

See "[Large Data and Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)" in the MSDN Library.

Do not use ASMX web services if you're interested in performance of large data transfers.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend WCF Data Services (or whatever it's called now). You can expose an oData endpoint which (if you have .NET on both sides of the webservice) gives you transparent request throttling (the server limits the number of responses in a single call, and the client automatically makes additional requests as necessary). It also gives you an `IQueryable`-style interface which is extremely flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is common : you have a lot of data to return to the user.

If you are lucky, you may get away by increasing the webservice timeout. Otherwise, would a solution of returning a pageful data at a time back to the user suits your requirements? In this design, the caller would be responsible for specifying the start page, and how many rows of data per page to your webservice.

See [Pagination Queries](https://web.archive.org/web/20100106025647/http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17asktom.html) and [Pagination tips](https://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_pagination.htm)

If however, you are not restricted to using webservice as a solution, then you might like to investigate offering Reporting Services to your users. Definitely worth your while to investigate this alternate option :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Paging is not really ideal because the data is coming from an Oracle view, and a large part of the slowdown is running the view.  So even if it were paged, each page would be very slow (unless I somehow kept the Oracle cursor open between calls...)

Comment: @Malvineous, you do not have to keep your cursor open between calls. See my updated links above. Hope it helps